# Ошибка при использовании Java Hibernate

Tags: oracle, jdbc, hibernate, java

Появилась надобность изучить Hibernate.
Начал изучать по примеру, нашел в интернете:

http://javaxblog.ru/article/java-hibernate-1/

Все сделал как в примере, отличие лишь в том, что базу я взял свою старую, которая стоит на компьютере в домашней локальной сети + версия Oracle DB 11g + драйвер я брал из библиотеки ojdbc14.jar (oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver), ибо с другими у меня какие то проблемы, как я понимаю с локализацией.

При старте проекта вылетает:

```
окт 04, 2013 2:11:55 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
окт 04, 2013 2:11:55 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final}
окт 04, 2013 2:11:55 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
окт 04, 2013 2:11:55 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
окт 04, 2013 2:11:55 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
окт 04, 2013 2:11:55 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
окт 04, 2013 2:11:56 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
окт 04, 2013 2:11:56 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
окт 04, 2013 2:11:56 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
окт 04, 2013 2:11:56 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10
окт 04, 2013 2:11:56 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
окт 04, 2013 2:11:56 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.115:1521:XE]
окт 04, 2013 2:11:56 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=alex, password=****, autocommit=false}
```

Т.е., как я понимаю, соединение прошло успешно, но следом:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.locatorsUpdateCopy()Z
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1861)
    at ru.morkoff.hibernatetest.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    at ru.morkoff.hibernatetest.hibernate.DAO.Impl.StudentDAOImpl.getAllStudents(StudentDAOImpl.java:70)
    at ru.morkoff.hibernatetest.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:32)
Java Result: 1
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194990/why-do-i-get-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-when-trying-to-load-a-blob-in-the-db), то это может произойти из-за того, что драйвер JDBC, используемый в вашем проекте, реализует более старую версию JDBC API, чем та, что используется в установленной JRE. Проверьте совместимость вашей версии драйвера JDBC с версией вашей JRE, скорее всего вам нужен более новый.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде заработало, поменял jdbc драйвер на ojdbc6.jar, тоже сначала не пошло, вылетели исключения ORA-00604 ORA-12705, собственно из-за этих ошибок я и стал год назад использовать более старый драйвер, так и не найдя действующего решения, сейчас решил путем добавления в код строки 

    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

перед началом взаимодействия с базой